# Let $f:[0,\alpha]\to \mathbb{R}$ solution of a Cauchy problem , prove $\alpha <3.$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $f:[0,\alpha] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a solution of the Cauchy problem 
$$ 
\begin{cases}
f'(t)=f(t)^2+t, \\
f(0)=0.
\end{cases}
$$
Prove that $\alpha <3.$

I know that I should try to prove that $f$ blows up to $+\infty$ before time $t=3$. I tried to apply the comparison theorem, but I cound't find a suitable function to use. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually the life span of $f$ is a bit less than $2$, given by a root of an Airy function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that $f'(t) \ge t$, so $f(t) \ge \frac 12 t^2$, in particular $f(1) \ge \frac 12$.

Second, $f$ can be compared with the solution $g$ of 
$$ \begin{cases} g'(t) = g(t)^2, \\ g(1) = \frac{1}{2}. \end{cases} $$ 
Since $f'(t) \ge f(t)^2$ and $f(1) \ge g(1)$, we have $f(t) \ge g(t)$ for $t \ge 1$.

But $g$ can be calculated to be $g(t) = \frac{1}{3-t}$, so $f$ blows up at time $t=3$ or earlier.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to do, but my mistake was trying to compare $f$ with a $g$ starting from 0.

Answer (score 4):

For any $t>0$ we have that $f'(t)$ is positive, hence $f(t)$ is increasing and invertible. Let $g=f^{-1}$.
We have $f(g(t))=t$, hence

$$ t^2+g(t) = f'(g(t)) = \frac{1}{g'(t)} $$
and from the positivity of $g(t)$ we may deduce $g'(t)\leq\frac{1}{g(t)}$, from which $g(t)\leq\sqrt{2t}$.
Let $t_0$ be the least time such that $g(t_0)\geq 1$. By the previous inequality, $t_0\geq\frac{1}{2}$.
From that point on, $g'(t)\leq\frac{1}{t^2+1}$, hence $g(t)$ is bounded by $1-\arctan t_0+\frac{\pi}{2}$.

In particular the life span of $f$ cannot exceed $1-\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}<\color{red}{2+\frac{1}{9}}$.

Comment: That's rather sharp, a numerical solution shows that it explodes at $t\approx 1.98635270743047$. It would be a challenge to prove analytically that it's $<2$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: that is an interesting question. Indeed it is possible to prove that the lifetime is $<2$ by exploiting the Gauss continued fraction of the hypergeometric function involved in the explicit solution. However, I guess that was not the purpose of the original question.

Comment: you're right, the exact solution can be written as $f(t)=-u'(t)/u(t)$, where $u$ can be expressed in terms of Airy functions of negative argument, or equivalently, Bessel functions of order $-1/3$: $u(x)=\sqrt{x}\,J_{-1/3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\,x^{3/2}\right).$ Those special functions are well understood, but I agree that the OP wanted to know just how much can be deduced immediately from the original differential equation.